# Running command line with arguments from c # with white space in path

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, development-environment

I have the follwoing c# code:

```
string cmdInnoSetup = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\compil32\""" + " /cc " + @"""c:\\SetupScript.iss""";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe","/k "+ cmdInnoSetup);
```

But when I execute it I got the following message:

> "Program not found"

But when I remove double quotation from second part sentence `"c:\\SetupScript.iss"`  then the code works fine!

Now how can I solve this illogical problem in order to keep both of paths inside double quotation !

**How to let code work by setting double quotation for source and destination as well!**

Comment: How to let code work by setting double quotation for source and destination as well!

Comment: why voting down! what is the FK !!

Comment: You also have an extra backslash in the file name. When you prefix the string with @ you shall not escape the backslash. So it should be @"""c:\SetupScript.iss""".

Comment: Why you insisting on saving both the paths within one string, why don't you save them within 2 separate strings?

Comment: i did it it doesnot work, please write if you have answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the string written like this:

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Inno Setup 5\\compil32\\\"" + " /cc \"c:\\SetupScript.iss\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this two lines, I tried it and it works:

```
string cmdInnoSetup = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\compil32.exe"" /cc 'c:\SetupScript.iss'";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k " + cmdInnoSetup);
```

Comment: I know this,  but I need to put c:\SetupScript.iss  inside double quotation as well

Comment: @MuradAlHaj I`ve updated the answer code. Again tested it and it works

Comment: @MuradAlHaj Is this the actual code you are testing? or it looks differently? Perhaps there is more data that might change how I try it

Comment: @MuradAlHaj Maybe our expectations are different. When you say it doesn`t work, what do you mean? What error do you get? Doesn`t the InnoSetup start?

Comment: The "Program " is not found.

Comment: @MuradAlHaj Odd... once I added the single qoute like so: string cmdInnoSetup = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\compil32.exe"" /cc 'c:\SetupScript.iss'"; it solved that issue. Did you put single qoute or double qoute around the iss file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling your program differently. Such as:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\compil32.exe", @"/cc ""c:\SetupScript.iss""");
```

Unless you really need the cmd to perform the output it should do basically the same.

(I didn't try it with InnoSetup myself but with another program)